# Docker daemon can't import tar with duplicate files

Tags: docker, tar

I've been following this tutorial to create a docker image from a buildroot environment:  https://blog.docker.com/2013/06/create-light-weight-docker-containers-buildroot/

Basically, the steps are:

1. Create the rootfs.tar as you would any other x86_64 buildroot environment
2. Create a filesystem overlay for the files:

   (a) /etc/resolv.conf and /sbin/init by `touch`ing

   (b) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0, /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6, and /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 by `cp`ing from the local filesystem
3. `tar r` the files (iow, append) to `rootfs.tar` to create `fixup.tar`
4. `docker import - tag < fixup.tar`

However, when I attempt to import this, docker returns:

```
Error response from daemon: Untar re-exec error: duplicates of file paths not supported: output:
```

I presume this is because `tar r` *appends* rather than *replaces* files, so tar has multiple indexes for the same file and this causes docker to be confused.

I looked around, but I couldn't find a newer version of this tutorial.

How does one go about correcting this so that I can create a docker image from a buildroot environment?

Comment: Incidentally, I opted out of creating the buildroot tag, but I'm equally surprised that it doesn't exist.  Anyone with more rep have any idea if this appropriate for a new tag?

Comment: Did you try just "tar -x" to "collapse" the appended files and then using "tar -c" to create your tar for importing into docker?

Comment: Yes.  It has issues with mknod creating special files.  May need fakeroot.  There has to be an easier way!